# create systemd nodejs express-generator

Tags: node.js, express

I have nodejs server that generate by express-generator.
Now i try to create systemd service to run my server.

```
[Unit]
Description=Node.js Example Server     

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/node /opt/nodeserver/server.js
Restart=always
StandardOutput=syslog               
StandardError=syslog                
SyslogIdentifier=nodejs-example
Environment=NODE_ENV=production PORT=1337

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The service can not run because i cant run the server with the command node server.js.
The only way i can run the server: npm server.js.
How can i tell the service run the server with npm command and not node?

Comment: Did [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40861258/create-systemd-nodejs-express-generator/40863613#40863613) help? Any comments?

Answer (score 0):

Systemd can be sometimes problematic. It's easier to write SysV or Upstart init scripts whenever you can. I explain some of the issues in those answers: [[1]](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5877/what-are-the-pros-cons-of-upstart-and-systemd/287282#287282), [[2]](https://askubuntu.com/a/787332/11582).

Now, what you can do is to write a startup script yourself that would:

1. change the working directory to your application
2. run the start command

For example:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /your/application/path
npm start
```

(or `npm server.js` or whatever your command is instead of `npm start`)

It may also be useful to set the correct PATH if you need it:

```
#!/bin/sh
PATH="/opt/node/bin:$PATH"
export PATH
cd /your/application/path
npm start
```

(where `/opt/node/bin` is where your `node` and `npm` are installed)

If you save such a script as e.g. `/opt/nodeserver/server.sh` then you should be able to use:

```
ExecStart=/bin/sh /opt/nodeserver/server.sh
```

in your systemd script (unless there are more gotchas in systemd that would cause problems here).